# Issue in archiving on XCode 4.2 application having mailcore

Tags: objective-c, email, archive, mailcore

I am preparing application using mailcore. I have done success full archived on XCode 3.2 after including the static Liberaries. But the same procedure I have followed on XCode 4.2.  I have also set the library search path and header search path according to XCode 4.2 .. It again gives me .xcarchive file rather than .ipa. I have followed this link..

[The workspace with the iOS project and related a static library project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390404/the-workspace-with-the-ios-project-and-related-a-static-library-project)

Is there any different procedure on XCode 4.2 for mailcore archiving..

Comment: After selecting Distribute... are you sure you choose Save for Enterprise of Ad-Hoc Development?

Comment: Sir ..The Distribute option comes after building .ipa not before it..

Comment: No, the Distribute option comes after creating an Archive, from Product menu. Selecting Distribute... I see the following options: Submit to the iOS App Store, Save for Enterprise of Ad-Hoc Deployment (this give you the .ipa), Export as Xcode Archive (this gives you the .xcarchive).